# EXCEL - How do I consolidate rows with duplicate information in one column but combine data in the other columns

Tags: vba, duplicate, microsoft-excel-365, combine

[Click to see example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS8fM.png)

I have a spreadsheet of incoming products and the shipping containers they are arriving on. I want to combine rows with duplicate items while preserving the quantities of that item in each container column. For this I've been using the following VBA code:

```vb
Sub combine()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each c In Range("A2", Cells(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1))
If c = c.Offset(1) And c <> "" Then
       For i = 1 To 6
            If c.Offset(1, i) <> "" Then
                c.Offset(, i) = c.Offset(1, i)
            End If
       Next
       c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next

End Sub
```

This code works great, however, sometimes these items have multiple rows with quantities in the same container. This code merely replaces the quantity above with the quantity below. I need them to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

```
Sub combine()

Dim c As Range
Dim i As Integer

For Each c In Range("A2", Cells(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1))
    If c = c.Offset(1) And c <> "" Then
        For i = 1 To 15
            If c.Offset(1, i) <> "" Then
                If c.Offset(, i).Value <> "" Then
                    c.Offset(, i) = c.Offset(, i) + c.Offset(1, i)
                Else
                    c.Offset(, i) = c.Offset(1, i)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        c.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```